# Android: Get current device orientation from service

Tags: android, orientation, screen-orientation, android-orientation, device-orientation

This question involves 3d geometry and solid understanding of Android sensors. I have spent weeks looking for a solution without success and would appreciate community help.

Is it possible to get the current device orientation (portrait or landscape) from a service in Android? I do not need continuous update from the sensors; just the current device orientation. The device orientation should report correctly when held in landscape even if the launcher is portrait (because the user has auto-rotate set to off).

Sample/example code will be highly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: found any solution to that?

Comment: You managed to find a solution?

Answer (score 3):

Yes you may

```
WindowManager windowService = (WindowManager) getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
int currentRatation = windowService.getDefaultDisplay().getRotation();

if (Surface.ROTATION_0 == currentRatation) {
   currentRatation = PORT;
} else if(Surface.ROTATION_180 == currentRatation) {
   currentRatation = PORT;
} else if(Surface.ROTATION_90 == currentRatation) {
   currentRatation = LAND;
} else if(Surface.ROTATION_270 == currentRatation) {
   currentRatation = LAND;
}
```

Comment: This does not work when device orientation is changed on top of home screen.This api works properly only when device screen orientation is changed.

Answer (score 1):

You can check resource in service by below

```
if (getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
//
} else {
//
}
```

Comment: This does not work when device orientation is changed on top of home screen.